# Saving Game Data In Windows Store App

Tags: unity, windows, filesystem

I am creating a windows store game using unity . I want to save the current high score data . I most probably use StreamReader / StreamWriter for saving data but when i build the executable for windows store app , the compiler is giving me a error that StreamReader class is not supported . Is there any alternate way for solving this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) provides a key-value store implemented in a platform appropriate manner.